# Prolog recursion appending

Tags: prolog, append

I'm currently trying to make a fact where I have:

```
    create_list(L1, [H|T], X, Y, Result)
```

where `L1` is an empty list, `[H|T]` is a list that's going to be given, `X` the X coordinate which is given and `Y` the Y coordinate which is also given. `Result` is going to be where the outcome is going to be stored.

```
     create_list(L1, [H|T], X, Y, Result) :- 
(H == c, P is X-1, append(L1,[(H, P, Y)], Result));
(H == b, P is X+1, append(L1,[(H, P, Y)], Result));
(H == e, P is Y-1, append(L1,[(H, X, P)], Result));
(H == d, P is Y+1, append(L1,[(H, X, P)], Result));
create_list(L1, T, X, Y, Result).
```

what this gives is

```
     ?- create_list([], [c,b,e], 2, 2, X).
X = [ (c, 1, 2)] ;
X = [ (b, 3, 2)] ;
X = [ (e, 2, 1)] ;
false.
```

and you see where `X` is given as 3 different lists? I want it to be just 1 `X` with all of them together like.

```
    ?- create_list([], [c,b,e], 2, 2, X).
X = [ (c, 1, 2), (b, 3, 2), (e, 2, 1)] 
false.
```

Comment: What do you mean by `L1` is an empty list?

Comment: @lurker This does do the job but when its joint, it is joint as in lists and not tuples: `Xs = [[ (c, 1, 2)], [ (b, 3, 2)], [ (e, 2, 1)]]` I needed it to be `Xs = [ (c, 1, 2), (b, 3, 2),  (e, 2, 1)].`